# Iterate in get_results SQL squery, PHP site

Tags: php

I have a php site where I want to send an email for all the users registered in database. I have something like this:

```
$db->get_results('select email from condominos2');
```

Now, how can I iterate each row and get/echo the email value as string?

Comment: Is this a wordpress site?

Comment: What framework are you using? You can probably do `$reults = $db->...` and loop them with a foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach.

```
$emails = $db->get_results("SELECT email FROM condominos2");

foreach ( $emails as $email )
{
    echo $email;
}
```

When you have multiple fields:

```
$users = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM condominos2");

foreach ( $users as $user )
{
    echo $user->email;
}
```